# How to access storage of a damaged Android phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, dd

So appparently Google or my Phone Company decided to change my firmware and my cellphone is there trying to boot but won't do so.

It loads the boot splash screen but it reboots again.

I would like to try to dd it and put Ubuntu Touch but I'm still not into Phone Dev ops. And I'm scared to install Ubuntu SDK phone eeulator along with Intel Microcode.

My phone model is Alcatel Idol 3 4.7"

Comment: What brand and model is your telephone?

Comment: @RostislavKandilarov Alcatel Idol 3 4.7"

Comment: You likely can't if it is stuck in a boot failure loop.  I ran into this issue with other Android devices and could only fix it by getting the manufacturer to fix it.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'll try that then

Comment: @userDepth Note that they may not be able to 'recover' the data on the device if the firmware update bricked it.  I also can't attest to every manufacturer or cell phone provider, and I would start by reaching to the phone company first before the manufacturer.  They may also charge you for the repairs.

Comment: @ThomasWard recovering the data is not my intent actually:)

Comment: Do you still need to fix this? If you don't want to recover data then root it, put a custom recovery on and then you can factory reset or install a 3rd party rom from the recovery menu, see: https://forum.xda-developers.com/idol-3/help/idol-3-complete-guide-to-getting-root-t3267400CDRDAO